# Can we tag YouTube videos in different languages?

Tags: video, youtube

I speak more than one language myself. But let me ask, if you have a video you know would be of interest to say people that speak hindi, would posting tags in Hindi and English help them find the video easier? Thats all I am asking.

my video lang in Hindi. Indian people search in English & Hindi(phonetic). But they want video lang in hindi.

So it's good to write keyword English & Hindi(phonetic)?
also it's good to write title English & Hindi(phonetic)?

Or Write in on only in English/Hindi

Answer (score 0):

It's probably usually better to write tags, titles and descriptions in the native language of your target audience. Better, I think, to have many tags in one language than one tag in many languages. Hope this helps.
For more info refer this link : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/_KsxXlIKbP8